# Python insert intoMySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I cannot see why my defined function does not work. No error message, just no INSERT into the Table

I define my function:

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="autot")
mycursor = db.cursor()

def writedb(Tablename,Time, trade_ID, Price, Quantity):
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO '{Tablename}' (Time, trade_ID, Price, Quantity) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", 
                     ({Time},{trade_ID}, {Price}, {Quantity}))
    db.commit()
```

I then use my function:

```
writedb(msft_price, 1678440087934, 240165117, 16.73000000, 97)
```

nothing happens...

Comment: You don't seem to call your function.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The db.commit() should be inside the scope of writedb, add a TAB

Comment: And by tab he means 4 spaces. :)

Comment: Thanks, just edited that !
But still nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Your statement uses {Tablename} but is not an f-string (meaning it doesn't start with f"...{Tablename}...".

Try using .format() instead of the current curly braces:

```
def writedb(Tablename, Time, trade_ID, Price, Quantity):
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO '{0}' (Time, trade_ID, Price, Quantity) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)".format(Tablename), 
                 (Time, trade_ID, Price, Quantity))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted the "Table name is not accessed by Pylance" message I had. But still nothing in the DB

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```html
import pymysql
conn=pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="autot")
cur  = conn.cursor()

def insertData(Tablename,Time,trade_ID,Price,Quantity):
    try :
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO '{Tablename}' (Time, trade_ID, Price, Quantity) VALUES ({Time},{trade_ID}, {Price}, {Quantity})")
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        conn.rollback()


insertData('msft_price', 1678440087934, 240165117, 16.73000000, 97)

conn.close()
```

Comment: thanks, but that has not worked

Answer (score 0):

Thank you community.
The problems lied around the single quotes around table name. I replaced them with back-ticks `